# When is a question answered?

Tags: discussion

Specifically I'm referencing this question: [Powershell: count members of a AD group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977379/powershell-count-members-of-a-ad-group/26977615#26977615)

I've answered the question asked about how to count the members in an AD group, but we are continuing to troubleshoot the OP's script as a whole in the comments.

Should I continue to help OP in this way? Should I ask that OP ask a new question?

Comment: You'll find a lot of information here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-vampire

Comment: [Here is another helpful post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: Thanks! This gives me some direction on where to go.